# Modify all elements in a python list and change the type from string to integer

Tags: python, list

I have a numerical list which looks like `['3,2,4', '21,211,43', '33,90,87']`
I guess at this point the elements are considered as strings.

I want to remove the  inverted comas and to make a list which with all these numbers.

Expected output is `[3,2,4, 21,211,43, 33,90,87]`

Also, I would like to know if the type of element is converted from to string to integer.

Somebody please help me!

Comment: `[int(x) for string in data for x in string.split(',')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following:

```
result = []
# iterate the string array
for part in ['3,2,4', '21,211,43', '33,90,87']:
    # split each part by , convert to int and extend the final result
    result.extend([int(x) for x in part.split(",")])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 ~/tmp/so.py 
[3, 2, 4, 21, 211, 43, 33, 90, 87]
```

Comment: What modifications would you do if the elements contain a character like '-'

For example, '2,3,-,5' is an element and you have to eliminate the '-'

Comment: @RuaGoa depends on how you want to treat `-`. If you just skip them, then `int(x) for x in part.split(",") if x != "-"` should be enough. If you want to make them 0s then you can just use `part.replace("-", "0")` before splitting. Finally, if you want to convert them to `None`, I would expand the generator into a second for-loop and use try/except to set to None all the values that were not ints

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 moving parts here:

1. splitting a list of strings
2. converting a string to integer
3. flattening a nested list

First one, [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> '1,2,3'.split(',')
['1', '2', '3']
```

Second one [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> int('2')
2
```

And last but not least, [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> [element for sublist in list_of_lists for element in sublist]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Putting all three parts together is left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> your_list = ['3,2,4', '21,211,43', '33,90,87']      
>>> your_list = [int(num) for item in your_list for num in item.split(",")]
>>> print(your_list)
[3, 2, 4, 21, 211, 43, 33, 90, 87]
```